# DXB (Dubai International Airport) Shuttle between Terminal 1 and Terminal 2

Tags: transit, dxb

I am arriving on Terminal 1 at DXB. From where exactly I can get shuttle to Terminal 2?

Comment: http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/flight-connections says "your airline will tell you what to do".  Have you asked them?

Comment: The [Dubai Airport website Flight Connections page](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/flight-connections) suggests that you need to head to Desk E on the lower level of T1 to get the bus over to T2. T1 is connected to T3, a short to medium distance away depending on gates. Perhaps someone heading through Dubai soon can wander down to the lower level and confirm?

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [Dubai Airports website](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/flight-connections), you will need to visit Transfer desk E (on the lower level of the airport). The transfer desk will guide you to the shuttle bus headed for Terminal 2.